# Getting syntax error at the end of the input while executing a query using postgres java driver

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-9.2

Have the following query that is giving error while executing through java driver, no errors while executing on DBVisualizer

```
SELECT pr.id,
       pr.name,
       CDPC.category_id,
       CDPC.category_depth,
       CDPC.product_count,
       pr.primary_category_id
FROM ics_products_to_include_tmp inc
  INNER JOIN catalog.products pr ON inc.product_id = pr.id
  INNER JOIN catalog.products_in_categories pic ON pic.product_id = pr.id AND pic.active = true
  INNER JOIN catalog.categories CC ON CC.id = pic.category_id AND CC.active = true
  INNER JOIN category_depth_product_count_tmp CDPC 
      ON CDPC.category_id = CC.id 
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM ics_products_cds_ids_tmp cds
                     WHERE cds.product_id = pr.id)
WHERE pr.site_id = '150'
ORDER BY pr.id
```

Here is the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Position: 495
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:381)
    at com.cnetchannel.ics.loader.IntermediateDatafeedGenerator.main(RRToIntermediateLoader.java:798)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51077', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: What driver do you use?

Comment: If `pr.site_id` is a numeric column you should not use single quotes for the comparison value. `'150'` is a string value, `150` is a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [Dollar-quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) notation.

Instead of having `pr.site_id = '150'` try it with something like

```
pr.site_id = $$150$$
```

Most probably your JDBC driver has problem distinguishing the two different quotes ' (&#39) and ` (&#96)